# PostgreSQL - Select row with composite maximum value from 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I would like to select the best offers for a merchant in PostgreSQL 9.6 according some simple rules:

- An offer is better than another if its discount value is greater regardless the benefit type
- If the discount values are equal, then the one with benefit type ALL beats the one with FOOD
- If both discount and benefit type are the same, then any offer can be selected e.g. pick the first one

So best is not just a max() call but a "conditional" max() where another column should be inspected too to determine which row it is.

Could you please help?

Schema:

```
create table offer (
    id bigserial not null,
    discount int4,
    benefit_type varchar(25),
    ...
    merchant_id int8 not null
);
```

Query (partial):

```
select merchant_id, max(discount) as max_discount
from offer
group by merchant_id;
```

Sample offers in DB:

```
id  discount    benefit_type    ... merchant_id
0   10          FOOD                0
1   20          FOOD                0
2   20          ALL                 0
3   30          ALL                 1
4   40          ALL                 1
5   40          FOOD                1
6   40          ALL                 2
7   50          FOOD                2
```

Desired result set:

```
merchant_id     max_discount    benefit_type
0               20              ALL
1               40              ALL
2               50              FOOD
```

- Merchant 0's best offer is offer 2 because 20 ALL > 20 FOOD.
- Merchant 1's best offer is offer 4 because 40 ALL > 30 ALL.
- Merchant 2's best offer is offer 5 because 50 FOOD > 40 ALL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved using `distinct on()` and a custom sort definition for the benefit_type:

```
select distinct on (merchant_id) *
from offer
order by merchant_id, 
         discount desc, 
         case when benefit_type = 'ALL' then 1 else 2 end;
```

This prefers higher discount. If two discounts are the same, a benefit_type of `ALL` is used as the tie-breaker.

Online example: http://rextester.com/TFBP17217

Comment: As a note:  The third condition can be simplified to `(benefit_type = 'All')::int desc`.